# How to be a good English Writer?

Tags: grammar

I know that we should know basics of Grammar to be a good writer, but which part of English Grammar is most important .And how to memorize Adjectives and phrases.
Kindly explain

Comment: I've forgotten most of the formal grammar I was ever taught, yet can still sling together adequate prose. Why? Because I read, write and speak the language every day, all day; except for occasional lapses into German or Latin. Practice, practice, practice. There are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should an appetite for reading. This might sound odd, but we all learn how to write by reading - the same as saying we learn how to speak by listening. As a second step, I'd recommend a good book on "Writing skills". Of course, one should have adequate knowledge of grammar. Let's not talk about "which part of grammar", because every bit of it is important. Least of all, memorizing 'adjectives and phrases'.

Comment: Sound advice, Sankarane. But not the sort ELU is intended to offer.

Comment: Correct. I realize that. ELU's mission isn't to offer personal advice, I think.

Comment: You'll notice that the question has been put on hold as inappropriate for ELU (and not because it's not a sensible question per se). I'd have close-voted myself, but essentially 'you need to take a 3-year course in language followed by a relevant course in writing' can be off-putting. But ELU is aimed at practised linguists rather than beginners / early intermediates, and encouraging questions like this is unhelpful.